# How can i populate my radiobutton from xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I have 1 label and 4 radiobutton controls(C#). How can i populate my controls from xml. In label from QuestionText and in radiobutton from Variant,but first question three variant , second question 4 variant.

```
<Questions>
<Question QuestionText="2*2">
  <Variants>
    <Variant>1</Variant>
    <Variant>4</Variant>
    <Variant>5</Variant>
  </Variants>
  <Answers>
    <Answer>4</Answer>
  </Answers>
</Question>
<Question QuestionText="3*2">
  <Variants>
    <Variant>1</Variant>
    <Variant>4</Variant>
    <Variant>5</Variant>
    <Variant>number</Variant>
  </Variants>
  <Answers>
    <Answer>4</Answer>
    <Answer>number</Answer>
  </Answers>
</Question>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Start trying and you'll do it

Answer (score 0):

You can try generate all radio buttons dynamically. Sample below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }       
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions
    {
        get { return _Questions; }
        set
        {
            _Questions = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Questions");
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Question> _Questions;

    ///read xml file and create object hierarchy
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        int groupCounter = 0;
        foreach (var questionElement in xml.Descendants("Question"))
        {
            Question question = new Question();
            question.QuestionText = (string)questionElement.Attribute("QuestionText");
            question.Variants = new ObservableCollection<Variant>();

            foreach(var variantElement in questionElement.Descendants("Variant")) 
            {
                Variant variant = new Variant() { VariantText = variantElement.Value, Group = groupCounter.ToString() };                                        
                question.Variants.Add(variant);
            }

            groupCounter++;
            Questions.Add(question);
        }            
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));            
    }        
}

public class Question : ViewModelBase
{
    public string QuestionText
    {
        get { return _QuestionText; }
        set
        {
            if (_QuestionText != value)
            {
                _QuestionText = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("QuestionText");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _QuestionText;

    public ObservableCollection<Variant> Variants
    {
        get { return _Variants; }
        set
        {
            _Variants = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Variants");
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Variant> _Variants;
}

public class Variant : ViewModelBase
{
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _IsChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsChecked != value)
            {
                _IsChecked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _IsChecked;

    public string VariantText
    {
        get { return _VariantText; }
        set
        {
            if (_VariantText != value)
            {
                _VariantText = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("VariantText");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _VariantText;

    public string Group
    {
        get { return _Group; }
        set
        {
            if (_Group != value)
            {
                _Group = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Group");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _Group;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding QuestionText}" />
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Variants}">                              
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton Content="{Binding VariantText}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" GroupName="{Binding Group}" />
                            </DataTemplate>                                
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                            
                    </ItemsControl>                        
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```